# Cannot find name ‘Let’(TS2304) ,’headers(TS2552)’, ‘options’ errors in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am a beginner with angular and ionic, I try to follow a tutorial and end up getting these errors.

- Cannot find name ‘Let’(TS2304)
- Cannot find name ‘headers’. Did you mean ‘Headers’?(TS2552)
- Cannot find name ‘options’. Did you mean ‘Option’?(TS2552)

Below is my code for access-providers.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

@Injectable()
export class AccessProviders {
    //url backend api json
    server: string ='http://localhost/login-register-home/api';

    constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

    postData(body, file){
        Let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        });
        Let options = {
            headers: headers
        }

        return this.http.post(this.server + file,JSON.stringify(body), options)
        .timeout(59000)// 59 sec timeout
        .map(res => res);
    }
}
```

Extra info:

- Angular CLI & Angular: 9.0.7
- Node: 12.16.1
- rxjs : 6.5.4
- typescript : 3.7.5

Can anyone help me out, I'm really clueless. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a typo. `Let` should be `let`. `let` is the keyword for declaring variables that can be updated. You can declare a variable in the following ways:

- `var options = {}`
- `let options = {}`
- `const options = {}`

You should use `const` whenever the variable itself isn't going to be updated.

```
const options = {};
options.prop = 'value'; // fine
options = {}; // error
```

You should use `let` in all other circumstances.

`var` is outdated and there is no reason to use it in Angular.